# python: Printing a function name with __name__ prints the decorator instead of the function name

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def test(testFunc):
    def runTest(*args, **kwargs):
        testFunc(*args, **kwargs)
    return runTest


@test
def func1():
    pass

@test
def func2():
    pass

tests = [func1, func2]

def RunTest():
   testList = [x.__name__ for x in tests ]
   print(testList)
```

Running above code prints `[runTest, runTest]` which is the name of the decorator. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]. What is `cleanup`? In any case, why do you *expect* it to print the name of the original function? Do you understand that your decorator returns another function, `runTest`?

Comment: @juanpa All the more surprising that it says “test” then…

Comment: fixed some of the errors in my question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) exists

By adding `@wraps(testFunc)` to your `runTest` function the names of the original function is retained. It essentially does something like this:

```
runTest.__name__ = testFunc.__name__
```

before returning `runTest`

This doesn't happen in your example because vanilla decorators are simply:

```
func1 = test(func1)
```

(`wraps` also copies any docstring from the wrapped function)

Just add `@wraps` to your inner function

```
def test(testFunc):
    @wraps(testFunc)
    def runTest(*args, **kwargs):
        testFunc(*args, **kwargs)
    return runTest
```

And you should get:

```
['func1', 'func2']
```

Comment: If this was the issue, the output should be “runTest”…

Comment: I assume that's due to the `cleanup` decorator which I have removed.